# New HTML5 Canvas API support

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, specifications

I have found several posts about new functions in HTML5 Canvas API, like Path primitives or Hit Regions.
It seems that the current specification (4.8.11) has got these features:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#hit-regions

Althought the context.addHitRegion (context is canvas2d context) in my Chrome 23.0.1271.64 returns undefined (I cannot create Path primitives too).

Does somebody know when these features will be implemented (their annoucment is from march so it is 8 months old)?

Can I test them in some beta versions of some browsers (it would be best if it could be under linux)?

Comment: Just a comment, not an answer : In the margin of the document you link to, the "implementation status" pretends there is nothing, whatever the browser.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't noticed it, but maybe is it possible to test it with some unstable branches of chrome or other browser? Are there any websites telling which part of specification are under development in specific browser?

Comment: I'm trying all that I know without any result for now... This question will probably end as too localized (short lived) but any documented answer would be very interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for a while.

I asked both the Chrome team and the Firefox team about 1-2 months ago and neither of them had a concrete timeline. It doesn't yet seem to be a priority.

In an email correspondence of mine with FF people on October 28th they replied:

> I assume you were referring to the Path / Pattern objects and related changes; there are—AFAIK—no immediate plans to implement them. Most of the work going into the 2D canvas implementation recently has been refactoring; in particular, we used to have two separate implementations, of which one has been removed a few weeks ago.

Comment: If you want paths and hit regions you can use SVG instead of `canvas`, so I'm guessing this will stay a low priority in the near future.

Comment: But SVG is not hardware accelerated and cannot handle so much graphic like canvas does, am I wrong?

Comment: You're correct, danilo2, and fast hit-testing is one of the major reasons for introducing these new Path objects to the Canvas spec.

Comment: @danilo2 I'm fairly sure that SVG is hardware accelerated on all the same platforms that `canvas` is hardware accelerated on, here's an [IE blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/08/comparing-hardware-accelerated-svg-across-browsers-with-santa-s-workshop.aspx) from 18 months ago when all the implementations were at an early stage.  If you have more recent information please share.

Comment: Regardless of acceleration, SVG objects contain massive overhead compared to paths drawn on a Canvas. There are a million performance tests/articles showing the difference, ie http://jsperf.com/html-vs-svg-vs-canvas/2 and http://joeloughton.com/blog/web-applications/svg-vs-canvas-performance/

Comment: While that is completely true, yf you want users to be clicking on the objects there's a practical minimum size they can be, and so a limit to how many you're going to need in a finite screen area.